# Unlimited Scroll in Terminator

Tags: 14.04, terminator

I'm using Terminator version 0.97.
Is there a way that I can scroll unlimited? In the current version I only can scroll back limited history

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I found the answer
Just right click on the Terminator -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Scrolling and select Inifinite scrollback

Comment: Even though I upvoted this some time ago, it stopped working for me(Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: On 18.04 it works for me.

Comment: I had to do SHIFT + Middle Mouse Click

Comment: I just cant tell enough how I am happy to find that the solution is how to navigate menus and not running another command ...  [editing after few seconds] daaaamn just realized that the other answer does indeed ask about doing some commands ... 

Comment: I had to use `Shift + F10` on terminator 1.91 and Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 21):

Open the terminator config file (usually located at the `$HOME` dir)

```
gedit ~/.config/terminator/config
```

under the `[profiles]` entry add those lines

```
  [[default]]
    scrollback_infinite = True
```

Now save and exit then restart your terminator. enjoy

Comment: This file doesn't exist for me...